# How writing a dominant 7 sus4 chord in RNA ( Vsus7 chord in the 1st inversion)

Tags: notation, roman-numerals, figured-bass

Maybe I’ve just a black out. But I wanted to notate a V7sus (inversion 1)  writing a dominant 7 without  the suspension of the 4th in RNA. No idea ...

g,c,d,f => c,d,f,g

Comment: Could I ask the person who voted to reopen to comment why this question was incorrectly closed as duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suspension won't be shown in the Roman numerals, but it *can* be shown in the figured bass:

[image]

As long as we remember that figured bass shows the intervals above the bottom pitch, it just becomes a simple counting exercise.

Combined with Roman numerals, we would label beats 3 and 4 of the first measure as a V chord, and we just have to understand that the C on beat 3 is a suspension:

[image]

For a related question, see [Figured bass 52?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/80287/21766)

Comment: I returned to edit my answer with a suggestion to use a 45 figure, realized I misunderstood the inversion aspect, and removed my answer entirely. Richard's answer makes perfectly clear what to do.