# How is Vsus7 written in Roman numbers if 1st inversion? (any seventh chord with sus4)

Tags: chord-theory, chord-inversions

I'm analyzing a fugue in G-minor (BWV 105) by Bach that starts with Gmsus4 la-re-mi-so (G-C-D-F) 1st inversion (re-mi-so-la =C-D-F-G). I wonder what the R.N. assignment will be ...

The Thorough bass notation I think is i246, yes?

Is this the same for the analysis in Roman numbers? i246?

In the 2nd example we have Dm4 (Bassnote=4=G)

In the full score we have the root chord in the accompaniment. (1st example)

[image]

the 2nd example is like my question asks:

G=4, then D,A,D, and even C (Alt)

[image]

Comment: Please add an indication of where the chord occurs in the images posted.

Comment: I don't know how to draw in there. It's the 1st tied note in the bass line. I thinks the question could be answered even without notation examples. e.g. V7sus4 in C: GCDF,   3rd inversion CDFG, oh sorry, it's the 1st inversion. CDFG!

Comment: So you're asking about the first two beats of the second measure in the image?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question. (it was so confusing to inverse the simple notation: the sus4 is in the bass voice.)

Comment: Posting the full score changes everything. Highly recommend getting rid of the first two images, which only confuse the question.

Comment: Deleted! As you can see it‘s the 5th-fall progression. Very nice music, btw.

Comment: See the linked question. The Roman numeral and figured bass (i.e. intervals) should be considered separately. So the Roman numeral would reflect the chord of resolution, and the figures would reflect the actual intervals present above the bass.

Comment: Again, Aaron, apologize  for wasting your time. Yes, but the link says its confusing .... http://www.sfcmtheory.com/harmony_supplements/chap_21.htm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119829/discussion-between-aaron-and-albrecht-hugli).

Comment: Thank you, Aaron.  (I‘ve been out). No need to chat, everything is clear now.

Comment: Actually, I thought all the comments would get moved to chat. Anyway, I gather you saw my message there. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example (-ger ge-recht, vor dir wird) without accounting for the suspension I think it would be...

`Gm: ...V V4/2 | i6 Dm: IV V4/2 | i6...`

...the suspension is in the bass at `Dm: i6`

I thought the usual way to analyze it is with suspension figures *above* the Roman numerals...

```
    4-3
Dm: i6
```

If that were given without a score, I think it might take a bit of thought to understand the meaning: a `i` chord, first inversion, third is in the bass, but the bass is suspended at the fourth above the root prior to dropping down to the third to give a normal `6/3` chord.

Also, I thought in [other posts](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82331) we have seen the figured bass part of Roman numeral analysis would take the figures for the intervals above the bass, and I think that for this example it would be...

`Dm: i5/2 i6/3`