# How would you write an inversion of a suspended chord with functional chord symbols?

Tags: notation, roman-numerals, functional-harmony

Ex.
[image]

Would the second chord be written as I<sup>7 - 6</sup> or I<sub>6</sub><sup>2 - 1</sup>?

Comment: Which do you think is correct?

Comment: @AndrewChin My first idea was to label it I7 - 6, but I7 is also a dominant 7th chord. The other option doesn't show the intervals between the upper 3 notes and the bass.

Comment: Technically, a I can’t be a *dominant* 7th, but I’m nitpicking. Aaron’s right, this has been covered before, though that other Q/A is a bit confusing. I’m not sure I agree with the accepted answer that it’s “more common” to just not show the suspension in the roman numerals, but check out the Aldwell & Schachter page it links to. That’s what I’m used to —that is to say, yes, I7—6.

Comment: If it were in root position the figured bass would more idiomatically be written 9-8 rather than 2-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, this previous post [How writing a dominant 7 sus4 chord in RNA ( Vsus7 chord in the 1st inversion)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82331/) provides the best answer, because it gives the *method* to determine the numeric figures to add to Roman numeral analysis regardless of what type of chord is being analyzed. It's a shame that others closed such a good post.

Anyway, according to that method, you write the numeric figures based on the *intervals above the bass*.

Your second option - `2-1` - looks like scale degree numbers, but you don't want to use those.

The bass is `E` and the suspended note above is a `D` which is a *seventh above the bass*. So, the chord is `I`, but given the bass the intervals above the bass as `3/6/7`. So, it's `I3/6/7`.

FWIW, the chord is *not* a seventh chord, and of course, it is not a ninth chord. The point of the suspension figure is to recognize the `D` is *not a chord tone*. One way to analyze this passage is to just write `V4/2 I6` below for the *chords*, and for the suspension figure, a melodic aspect, just put `sus`, or `9-8` above the `D` in the treble clef. (See @phoogs comment about `9-8` versus `2-1`.)

Personally, I think `I3/6/7` is hard to read and understand. `V4/2 I6` with `sus` or `9-8` keeps harmonic analysis symbols with chords and non-chord tone analysis separate with suspension figures.